# Extend root partition (and optionally move), after getting rid of windows

Tags: partitioning, gparted

I know, the question was asked many times and it's all over unix forums but I already spent hours trying to implement methods from there, but they're either not working to me or too confusing. So I actually want to ask 3 questions:

1. The best way to take some snapshot of my system so I could format the entire HDD and write it over? Is it even possible?
2. Any way to extend root partition (preferably without reboot) by using unallocated space in the beginning of the disk?
3. Move **/sda3** to the end of the disk (making it **/sda2**) and reserve all the rest of the space for root partition (**/sda1**)?

Here's screenshot from gparted:

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Please ask only one question at the time

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is to boot from LiveCD and use gparted.

1. Move sda3 left.
2. Extend sda4 left.
3. Move sda5 left.
4. Extend sda6 left.
5. Run in terminal

   ```
   sudo mount /dev/sda6 /mnt
   sudo chroot /mnt
   sudo grub-install /dev/sda
   exit
   ```

This way you will keep the NTFS partition sda3. But it is not recommended to keep NTFS partitions when you do not have Windows installed.

It is much better to backup all data from it and then remove it instead of moving.

Comment: alright that makes sense. What LiveCD would you recommend?

Comment: Obviously Ubuntu LiveCD.